# pagination for particular condition in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0

```
var $paginate = array(
            'limit' => 10,
            'order' => array(
              'Listing.id' => 'desc'
            )
                    );

 function admin_view_specific_advertiser($id=null) {

...other code...

$this->set('listings', $this->Listing->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Advertiser.id'=>$id))),$this->paginate());

}

URL:http://www.example.com/admin/listings/view_specific_advertiser/4
```

Total Listings=100

Numbers Listings of Advertiser Having id 4 = 50

Pagination Display:

```
Page 1 of 10, showing 10 records out of 100 total
```

The problem is pagination shows only listing data.I want to paginate the total records of only that particular advertiser(4 in this case).

It should display like this,

```
Page 1 of 5, showing 10 records out of 50 total
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your condition isn pagination

```
  var $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 10,
        'conditions'=>array('model.field'=>'value'),
        'order' => array(
          'Listing.id' => 'desc'
        )
      );
```

It this way u can add conditions in pagination

Comment: thanks for your replay.But i have tried this before.By the way i got the exact answer i was searching.

$this->set('listings', $this->paginate('Listing', array("Listing.advertiser_id = {$id}",'Listing.deleted=0')));